# Is it permissible to upload a women mehndi/henna designs website

Tags: halal-haram, business

Asslam-o-Alaikum.
I'm making an app which contains henna/mehndi designs for women. The images just contains the mehndi designs on arms and foot. This app is specifically and only for women. I'm making a starting screen to confirm that the user is only a woman.
So can you please guide me if it is good to upload an app like this. And please tell me if someone cheats like a man confirms gender as a woman then will I be sinful for this Or a woman shows the images to a man.
Please guide me.
JazakAllah